# Unhandled exception (4.1.15.0, postsharp.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.378758, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException

Tags: postsharp

I have updated PostSharp from `v 4.1.3-alpha` to `v 4.1.15`. There is no issue when I build on my local developer box, but when queueing a gated build it's failing on build server with the following error:

> Unhandled exception (4.1.15.0, postsharp.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.378758, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. [Public key mismatch]

I updated to the same version from `v 4.1.6-alpha` in a different solution and build server could build it successfully.

Can any one help me in understanding why PostSharp is looking for mscorlib `v 2.0.5.0` when all the projects in the solution are targeting .NET `v 4.5.1`?
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: mscorlib  v2.0.5.0 is the PCL version. Is the PCL profile installed on your build server?

Comment: I don't think we use any PCL , however i don't know how to check if PCL profile is installed on build server also don't have access to build server, if you can provide steps, I can ask my support team to check that.

Comment: It can be one of your references that is a PCL. You should have Microsoft Build Tools 2013 installed on the build server. You can also check reference assemblies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable`. Additionally, you can inspect `obj/Debug/Before-PostSharp` directory of the failing project and tell us which assembly does reference `mscorlib, v2.0.5.0`. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Having the exact same problem here, using PostSharp 4.1.19.0 - MS Build Tools 2013 installed on build server and no references to PCL for the assembly foud in Before-PostSharp dir. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @WimHollebrandse Could you please contact our support (https://www.postsharp.net/support) and send us the build log and content of `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\InstalledFrameworks` directory? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Daniel - I have sent this info to the info@postsharp e-mail addy. Cheers.